# CloudFormation S3 Bucket Policy invalid action error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am getting following exception Policy invalid action on s3 bucket policy.

I have following actions:

- ListObjects
- GetObject
- PutObject

Comment: Your policy has a single statement that mixes bucket-level and object-level actions against the bucket ARN and against a wildcard object resource ARN. You should instead have two statements: the first including only bucket-level actions and applied to the bucket resource, the second including only the object-level actions and applied to the wildcard object resource ARN.

Comment: Please post your cloudformation template.

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably because `ListObjects` is not a valid action for policy use.

Valid `List*` actions for S3 from policy generator:

[image]

And also from IAM console:

[image]

Also `AccountIds` could cause problems, but its form is not shown in your question.

Comment: @PranavMahajan Not all actions can be used in policies. I will extend the answer.

Comment: @PranavMahajan No problem. Have you removed it and it worked or still some issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215249/discussion-between-pranav-mahajan-and-marcin).

Comment: @anonymous Sorry couldn't be earlier online. How did it go?